# Can Greasemonkey work with the file:// protocol?

Tags: greasemonkey, filepath, url-scheme

I have a simple Greasemonkey script:

```
// ==UserScript== 
// @name hello
// @namespace http://www.webmonkey.com 
// @description A test of accessing documents using file:// protocol
// @include     http* file*
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

alert("hi");
```

It works fine as long as the URL is of the form `http://...` How do I also get the script to run on URLs of the form `file://...`?

In the User Settings section I have `http://*` and `file://*` as the included pages and in the Script Settings section I have `http* file*` in the "Included Pages" box.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See ["Greaseable schemes" in the Greasemonkey docs](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Include_and_exclude_rules#Greaseable_schemes).  Greasemonkey ignores the `file://` protocol by default.

For scripts to work with `file://` paths, you need to open [about:config](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About%3aconfig) and set `extensions.greasemonkey.fileIsGreaseable` to `true`.

You might possibly have to restart Firefox for this setting to take effect.

---

---

Also, `// @include  http* file*` is invalid syntax.  You would use:

```
// @include     http://*
// @include     https://*
// @include     file://*
```

except, **avoid using such global includes** as much as you can.   Tune to the script to just the domain(s) and/or page(s) you explicitly target.

This: avoids unexpected side effects, increases performance, and reduces the chances of being pwned by some "zero day" exploit.

---

I also recommend that you delete the *User Settings* options for scripts you write yourself.  This will only lead to heartache and confusion later. ;)  Use the metadata section of the script, only, for scripts you control.

Comment: Thank you, sir. I would have given you a vote up but I'm too new to be able to do that. FYI, I didn't have to restart Firefox for the setting change to take effect.

Comment: Just to note: "file" is now denied from http(s) in greasemonkey

Comment: @feildmaster, that is a defect with GM 4, one of dozens.  It's one more reason why even the lead controller of GM says to switch to Tampermonkey or Violentmonkey.  Note that [greasemonkey-4](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/greasemonkey-4/info) is a separate tag from [greasemonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/greasemonkey/info).