# What should I do to execute grease monkey in local html file

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

In a html file of the local pc directory, I want to execute grease monkey.
I was not able to execute the following file.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        test
// @namespace   aaa
// @include     file:///C:/fx/test/a.html
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==
alert('c');
```

What should I do to execute grease monkey in local html file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19910568/can-greasemonkey-work-with-the-file-protocol this can be useful for you,a duplicate question

Comment: It was settled by a linked method.
Thank you.